# In Pacific Rim, why aren't Jaegers pilots crushed by extreme accelerations?

Tags: pacific-rim, jaeger

How come crews from [Red Baron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Baron_%28anime%29) and [Pacific Rim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Rim_%28film%29) are not injured by intense acceleration of humanoid warmachine while piloting from inside?

- They fall from great distances and continue walking without a hitch.
- When pilots receive a strong punch by enemies, they shake their heads and also shaking the machine's head and this would lead to coupling of both shakings(pilot+robot) and dizziness.
- There are numerous battles that robots spin around and that would just slap the pilot to inner wall. With the control constraints attached, pilots must be under more than 10G acceleration.

[Neon Genesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion) 's pilots are positioned closer to center of mass(maybe to stay away from  linear and angular accelerations as much as possible) and control capsule is filled with liquid(balancing the forces through fluid pressure?)

- Are there any gyroscopic mechanisms that keep the pilot lightly affected by rotations?
- Are there any elevator mechanism that have the pilot in tune with obstacles such as amortising insane vertical acceleration?

Especially the stadium crash scene. Maybe 300 meters per second to 0 meters per second under 0.2 second.

Comment: Hello. I'll edit the title of your question, rollback if you don't like it, but please be sure to put an explicit one.

Comment: Yes, thats explaining better. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**The control pods or [Conn-Pods](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Conn-Pod) where the pilots are hung are designed to hold the pilot with an independent hydraulic system whose goal is to protect the pilots from the external forces the Jaegers are subjected to.**

[image]

You can see the system connects the pilot to an armature which is supposed to protect the pilot from those forces. It is mounted on the back of the suit and supports the spine, hips and shoulders.

> Conn-Pods are traditionally mounted on the shoulders of the Jaeger, furthering their loosely humanoid appearance. This carries over with most Jaegers, such as Gipsy Danger, Crimson Typhoon or Striker Eureka. However, there are exceptions: the Russian Jaeger, Cherno Alpha's Conn-Pod is located in the chest area, as the the space on the shoulders is taken up by the machine's massive power plant.

Realistically, this would likely be a design nightmare, but the movie presupposes this is possible. You can see how this was supposed to be accomplished by looking at the Behind the Scenes videos by the company which designed the control pods, Legacy Effects. I have included the video because I believe it will shed sufficient light on what their intent was.

Comment: Does the liquid that's shown cycling through the helmets during the "suiting up" scene in the beginning of the movie have anything to do with absorbing shock?

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly guess that pilots in these stories are not affected by accelerations because the storywriters don't know squat about physics. Or they know and choose to ignore it to make writing easier (to their defense, the audience might not always react well to a physically accurate story).

Also, you cannot absorb acceleration with water. Water is an uncompressible liquid, hence its use in hydraulic systems...

Comment: What if its compressable liquid?,

Comment: You can absorb acceleration with a water (or any non-compressible liquid) if it is allowed to flow through baffles.  This how oil shocks work on a mountain bike. That being said, I am not sure if that is how the system the OP describes is set up.

Comment: Water *is* compressible, just not dramatically so. Hydraulic systems use it - when they're not using some kind of oil - because it's "good enough" and cheap.

Answer (score 1):

The pilots are suspended via the armature which presumably compensates for sudden jolts and the like. Also, they are not in the head of the Jaeger but in it's torso. So there shouldn't be much motion regardless of what's happening.

Comment: They are in the head of at least some of the Jaegers. [The schematics for Gipsy Danger](http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/underwire/2012/11/JaegerGipsyDanger.jpg) clearly show that the pilots are in the head.

Comment: well that's just plain dumb. Let's put the people controlling the machine in the most vunerable and least useful part. I could have sworn that when his brother was pulled out they were in the torso. Gipsy Danger was one of the earlier Jaegers right?

Comment: It's a Mark-3 (3rd year of rollouts), but even [Striker Eureka](http://images.wikia.com/pacificrim/images/8/88/Striker-Eureka-Australian-Jaeger_jpg.jpg), the last Mark-5 built put the pilots in the head. [Cerno Alpha](http://images.wikia.com/pacificrim/images/6/63/Cerno_Aplha.jpg) - a Mark-1, had the pilots in the chest, but [Coyote Tango](http://images.wikia.com/pacificrim/images/1/1f/Cyote_Tango.jpg) - another Mark-1, did not.

Comment: Wow...you really dove into this universe huh? I really enjoyed the movie a lot and would love to see more media from that universe (books especially).

Comment: @MichaelBrown I think thats because of nuclear reactor being too dangerous when close to them. Maybe control unit moves between head and torso, thats why stadium fall scene was not lethal.